# Python webapp run with multiple processes/workers server and watchdog thread

Tags: python, django, multithreading, webserver, python-multiprocessing

I need help to find out how to deal with following scenario:

During (Django) web app startup, a watchdog observer thread is being run in background also. If watchdog detects new file in a folder, it moves the file into another location.

While it works well with Django runserver --noreload, it breaks, when I run with runserver in autoreload mode. I think the same issue will occur if I run it with e.g. uwsgi with multiple workers.

Why it breaks? Because each process gets notification about the new file and if first of them moves that file to another location, second one breaks with:

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
```

The error is related to the file which is supposed to be moved, but it's not there, because the file has been moved already.

First question is: does autoreload mode of runserver is similar to uwsgi with 2 workers?

Second: how to deal with it?

I know I experienced similar challenges in the past related to different use case (without watchdog involved and with uwsgi) and wonder if you guys can help me to learn how to deal with such scenarios. Maybe you got some good reads about the topic.

Regards,
okrutny